# Lattice full plot area

Tags: r, raster, lattice, rastervis

I want to delete R's default margin around the lattice plot. This means that I want to get rid of all the white spaces beyond the red rectangular. Here is the example:

```
library (raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
levelplot(r, margin=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the margins with the `layout.heights` and `layout.widths` arguments to `lattice.options`:

```
lattice.options(
  layout.heights=list(bottom.padding=list(x=0), top.padding=list(x=0)),
  layout.widths=list(left.padding=list(x=0), right.padding=list(x=0))
)
levelplot(r, margin=TRUE)
```

[image]

Select the image above (e.g. by clicking to the right of it and dragging left) to verify that the margins are as expected.

However, white space will still fill the horizontal extent of the graphics device, so you need to either adjust the `xlim` so that the white space is *within* the plot rather than outside it, or just adjust the width of the device appropriately. I did the latter, which might take a bit of trial and error if plotting to a file, but which is straightforward if plotting to an `x11`/`windows`/`quartz` device (just resize the pane).